# How to UnitTest Django Rest Framework Serializers's create method?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-validation

How to test the **`create method of serializer`** ?

Comment: Checkout [**field level validation**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) and [**object level validation**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation)

Comment: ok, Let me checkout this docs.
Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Field Level

You can specify custom field-level validation by adding .validate_ methods to your Serializer subclass. These are similar to the .clean_ methods on Django forms.

These methods take a single argument, which is the field value that requires validation.

Your validate_ methods should return the validated value or raise a serializers.ValidationError. For example:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = serializers.CharField()

    def validate_title(self, value):
        """
        Check that the blog post is about Django.
        """
        if 'django' not in value.lower():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Blog post is not about Django")
        return value
```

### Object-level validation

To do any other validation that requires access to multiple fields, add a method called .validate() to your Serializer subclass. This method takes a single argument, which is a dictionary of field values. It should raise a serializers.ValidationError if necessary, or just return the validated values. For example:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class EventSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    start = serializers.DateTimeField()
    finish = serializers.DateTimeField()

    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Check that start is before finish.
        """
        if data['start'] > data['finish']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("finish must occur after start")
        return data
```

### Validators

Individual fields on a serializer can include validators, by declaring them on the field instance, for example:

```
def multiple_of_ten(value):
    if value % 10 != 0:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Not a multiple of ten')

class GameRecord(serializers.Serializer):
    score = IntegerField(validators=[multiple_of_ten])
    ...
```

Serializer classes can also include reusable validators that are applied to the complete set of field data. These validators are included by declaring them on an inner Meta class, like so:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    room_number = serializers.IntegerField(choices=[101, 102, 103, 201])
    date = serializers.DateField()

    class Meta:
        # Each room only has one event per day.
        validators = UniqueTogetherValidator(
            queryset=Event.objects.all(),
            fields=['room_number', 'date']
        )
```

Comment: Can I use dynamic validation, Like Support I want to change on one field from the database, using those changes, validation applied to other fields regarding my old key values change? Want to develop fully depending validation.

Comment: Hope you understand my question.

Comment: @VikasUkani of course you can do it but you need to specify them in `def validate(self, data):` function where you can simply get the configuration from the database and return value or raise exception accordingly

Comment: Is it possible to inherit some of those classes you described from ```serializers.ModelSerializer```? So I can combine automatic validation with custom.

Comment: @Aska of course, as `ModelSerializer` itself is inherited from `Serializer` class.